# Perl Mojo::Util::secure_compare vs eq

Tags: perl, hash, base64, mojolicious

In the [`Mojo::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Util#secure_compare) documentation for the method `secure_compare` it mentions

> Constant time comparison algorithm to prevent timing attacks.

Suppose I hash user input like this

```
my $b64_hash = Crypt::ScryptKDF::scrypt_b64($input_name, $secret);
```

is there any difference between result between

```
return Mojo::Utill::secure_compare($input_name_hash, $b64_hash);
```

and

```
return $input_name_hash eq $b64_hash;
```

Comment: Why don't you benchmark them?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you benchmark them?

I would say that `secure_compare` will always be much 
slower than `eq`, but will always take the same time for strings of a given length, whereas `eq` will be quicker if the difference is earlier in the string, which is as advertised